# how to use regular expressions in terraform to denote multiple resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-iam-policy

I have a statement in terraform that is as follows:

```
statement {
    sid    = "DenyDelete"
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "iam:Delete*"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/(?!userA|userB)",
    ]
}
```

With this statement I am hoping to deny `iam:delete` actions on all users except userA and userB. i.e. the regex will match any string that starts with `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/` and is followed by anything but `userA` and `userB`. I have tested the regex `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user\/(?!userA|userB)` in https://regex101.com/ and I have confirmed it will match any user ARN except that of userA and userB. However, deploying this statement does not seem to give the desired results and I presume it is because I am using the regex syntax wrong in terraform - does anyone know the correct regex syntax so that resources will include all users except userA and userB? Note that I cannot use `NotResource` as that will include all other resources including non-users.

Comment: There are no regular expressions in IAM. So you can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more an AWS IAM question. You can use [wildcards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html) but not regular expressions.

If you want to protect a list of users and you them upfront you can add those into the `resources`. You said you can't use `NotResource`, but I think you could if you limit your action to `iam:DeleteUser` and leave the `iam:Delete*` to whatever you want, deny or allow.

If you users are tagged you can also use [ABAC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_attribute-based-access-control.html) (Attribute Based Access Control) instead of resource based. In this case you would write an IAM policy to check for a tag on the resources.
Something like:

```json
statement {
    sid    = "DenyDelete"
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [ 
      "iam:DeleteUser"
    ]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "iam:ResourceTag/ProtectedUser"
      values   = ["true"]
    }     
}
```